# How to pass arguments to commands in GNU make shell function?

Tags: makefile, sdl, gnu-make

I'm compiling a SDL program using a Makefile. Typically I can compile my SDL projects with `gcc` like so:

```
# gcc -c test.c `sdl-config --cflags`
# gcc -o test test.o `sdl-config --libs`
# ./test
```

I'm having trouble executing `sdl-config` in my Makefile however. This is what I have:

```
CFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --cflags)
LDFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --libs)

test : test.o
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o test test.o
test.o:
```

But I keep getting the `sdl-config` usage line back rather than the respective output. I suspect the arguments (`--cflags` and `--libs`) are not being passed to `sdl-config`.

How do I pass arguments to the `shell` function? Is there a better way to achieve my end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is correct.  If you run "sdl-config --cflags" from the command line, does it work or do you get the usage line?  The best way to debug scripting problems is to run the script from your shell prompt.  If it works there, it will work in make, too.

Comment: If I run `sdl-config --cflags` from the command line, I get the correct output not the usage line. I wonder if I have a hidden character in my actual Makefile that's throwing off `make` -- I'll go check it out.

Comment: It appears to be the same. Is there a `make` command which would let me see the value of CFLAGS by itself before it gets to `gcc`?

Comment: Oops, it was a typo! I wrote `--clags` rather than `--cflags`.

Comment: That's why it's good to cut and paste an example of the failing makefile into your SO question, instead of retyping it... you never know what issues may be added or removed during the retyping process :-)